# Огромное количество подключений к mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

Использую tomcat8, ubuntu 16.04, mogodb, при каждом запросе к моему сервлету, делается запрос к базе данных.
Создан отдельный класс, MongoClient - static поле класса, инициализируется в конструкторе:

```
private static MongoClient mongo;

public DatabaseHandler() {
    mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
}
```

В методах я использую этот клиент, но базу данных и коллекции беру каждый раз заново, или же также делаю статическими полями, без разницы:

```
public String getSomeData() {
    ...
    MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("database_name");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("coll_name");
    ...
}
```

В классе, откуда я обращаюсь к базе данных, создан экземпляр этого класса, и я в коде неоднократно обращаюсь к нему:

```
private static DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler();

...

public void someMethod1() {
    ...
    String a = databaseHandler.getSomeData();
    ...
}

...

public void someMethod2() {
    ...
    String b = databaseHandler.getAnotherData();
    ...
}

...
```

В итоге получается вот что:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И это не полностью, таких строчек слишком много. В чём проблема? Так и должно быть? Как исправить? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Как минимум не стоит инициализировать статическое поле в нестатическом конструкторе, для этого есть static-блоки. У вас сейчас при вызове второго конструктора предыдущее значение поля утекает.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin а покажите как у вас сейчас реализовано инициализация private static MongoClient mongo;

Comment: @PeterSamokhin   а после обращения к базе данных  вы закрываете к  ней коннект. Я не имею опыта работы с Mongo DB но обычно коннекшн нужно открывать и закрывать, если вы этого не делаете или классов MongoClient  у вас более чем 1 то может быть ситуация с незакрытыми соединениями.

Comment: Покажите код инициализации MongoClient

Comment: Если вдруг у вас больше одного MongoClient вам  нужно позаботиться об их закрытии, смотреть https://stackoverflow.com/a/8968243/5634351

Comment: Вам нужно убедится для начала что  у вас всего одно подключение к базе данных. Я не вижу всего кода и не вижу кто у вас создает и вызывает обьекты DatabaseHandler. Возможно вам нужно сделать и этого класа singleton, вот пример: https://crunchify.com/thread-safe-and-a-fast-singleton-implementation-in-java/

Comment: @PeterSamokhin если вы инициализируете так как показано в вашем вопросе - то там уже ошибка, вам статическая переменная ничего не изменить если просто каждый раз создаете новый объект и присваиваете его MongoClient mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из того количества кода которое вы предоставили, могу предположить что  проблема в классе `DatabaseHandler` и обращению к его переменной `MongoClient`. Вот пример того как мог бы выглядеть этот класс:

```
public class DatabaseHandler{

    private static DatabaseHandler instance;
    private MongoClient client;

    public static DatabaseHandler getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            synchronized(DatabaseHandler.class){
                if(instance == null){
                    instance == new DatabaseHandler();
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private DatabaseHandler() {
        client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    }

    public MongoClient getClient(){
        return this.client;
    }
}
```

Comment: Количество подключений сократилось, но всё равно их несколько, хотя используется mongo только в одном сервлете. Не знаете, в чём может быть причина?

Comment: Можете уточнить сколько было и сколько в  данный момент получается соединений? Возможно, вы где то, помимо класса DatabaseHandler инициализируйте  объект MongoClient. Убедитесь ,что в код вы получаете доступ к монго только через DatabaseHandler.

Comment: если я ограничу количество подключений при создании клиента, то будут использоваться уже открытые коннекты, или будет вылазить ошибка?

Comment: Как я уже говорил выше, я не имею опыта работать непосредственно с Mongo, но как правило, много конектов к базе данных - плохая практика. Скорее всего вам нужно всего одно подключение к базе данных и ошибок по-идеи быть не должно. Либо использовать ConnectionPool если такие есть в  Mongo, вам это может позволить держать определенное количество коннектов  не создавая лишних.